# Incomplete reads from file written by Popen()-based subprocess

Tags: python, file-io, popen

i'm trying to read the output from one function into another one.

if i break things down into two steps, call the first function(journal.py) from the command line, and then call the second(ip_list.py) i get the results that i'm looking for.

if i try to import the first and run it in the second the resulting list is empty.

```
import re
import journal

journal.journal()
ip_list = []
with open('Invalid_names_file') as file1:
    print(file1)
    a = [re.search(r'((\d+\.)+\d+)', line).group() for line in file1]
    print(a)
    for x in a:
        if x not in ip_list:
            ip_list.append(x)

print(ip_list)
```

output ->

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Invalid_names_file' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
[]
[]
```

when called in this manner, the file that i'm opening is there (once the script is done running), with what i'm expecting, yet i can't get it to read from it when i try to include it with the import.

i have the print()s so that i can try to understand what's happening, yet can't get my head around it.

journal.py is a Popen command that writes the file.

edit for chris

journal.py

```
from subprocess import Popen
import os

def journal():
    with open('Invalid_names_file', 'w') as Invalid_names_file:
        Popen('journalctl -u sshd.service --no-pager --since -168hours\
                --until today | grep Invalid', stdout=Invalid_names_file,\
                universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, shell=True)
        if os.stat('Invalid_names_file').st_size == 0:
            Popen('journalctl -u ssh.service --no-pager --since -168hours\
                    --until today | grep Invalid', stdout=Invalid_names_file,\
                    universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1, shell=True)
    Invalid_names_file.close()
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of the file? My assumptions: 1) `journal` does not close the file 2) your regex doesn't work

Comment: the regex does work. a line to be read will look like this 'Sep 15 22:00:52 testing sshd[4588]: Invalid user marilyn from 192.168.122.10 port 35630' the file that this is part of can be from zero to ...many lines long, and the regex will drop it down to one occurance of each ip address.  so if ...10 shows up 13 times, it will only be appended to list once.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, when it *exits* it necessarily closes the file, so if the OP were blocking on process completion there couldn't be any issue there.

Comment: ok but OP did not provide the `journal` code. I'm always doing the legwork here :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, i added(edited) it before i seen your comment.  thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for `Popen()` to finish.
Assign its return value to a variable and call `wait()` on it:

```
p = Popen('journalctl ...')
p.wait()
```

When you run the journal script separately, the parent process will only return when all of its children have terminated.
However, `Popen()` doesn't wait – unless you tell it to.
Thus, in your case, the `journal()` function exits immediately after starting the subprocess, so by the time you're reading the target file, it is still empty or incomplete.

Comment: thank you lenz.  i didn't know if i was having a race issue with that or not.  was looking at io, yet that wasn't helping at all.

Comment: I think the docs aren't very instructive on how to use `Popen()`. It seems like they're encouraging more the use of the module functions `call()` and `check_output()` etc.